# "X" messing up my code

Tags: functions, warning-messages

[image]

Hi everyone,

Sometimes I get an transparent x in my code that makes it run with errors. Does anyone know what this means? I've been searching for an answer but I guess I suck at searching, LOL =^).

Comment: That x is not messing up your code. It is just reminding you that whitespace is interpreted as multiplication in Mathematica.  You are probably trying to use newlines (i.e. whitespace) to separate several commands that are part of a larger expression. You need to use `;` for that.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. Now I feel stupid. Thank you so much!

Comment: Newlines work at the top level to separate several inputs, but subexpressions of a larger expression are always part of the same input.

Comment: @Göran No need to feel like this. We all have started somewhere. Welcome to Mathematica.StackExchange!